# Why does DataFrame.cumsum work with lists/strings, but GroupBy.cumsum doesn't?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, cumsum

With the following dataframe example

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "group": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "list": [[1], [2], [1], [2], [3]],
    "string": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "c"]
})
```

[`df.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) works fine

```
   group             list string
0      1              [1]      a
1      2           [1, 2]     ab
2      4        [1, 2, 1]    aba
3      6     [1, 2, 1, 2]   abab
4      8  [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]  ababc
```

but [`df.groupby("group").cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) doesn't, it seems to be designed only for columns with numeric dtype:

> FutureWarning: The default value of numeric_only in DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum is deprecated. In a future version, numeric_only will default to False. Either specify numeric_only or select only columns which should be valid for the function.
> df = df.groupby("group").cumsum()

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

My question is **why** is that the case? (I'm not looking for workarounds, I have a couple that work fine.)

If I [understand correctly](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L11233), then `DataFrame.cumsum` essentially delegates to [`numpy.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)

```py
    def cumsum(self, axis: Axis | None = None, skipna: bool_t = True, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._accum_func("cumsum", np.cumsum, axis, skipna, *args, **kwargs)
```

and `numpy.cumsum` is fine with lists/strings.

Whereas `GroupBy.cumsum` seems to involve [cythonisation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.3/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L3677):

```py
    def cumsum(self, axis=0, *args, **kwargs) -> NDFrameT:
        """
        Cumulative sum for each group.
        Returns
        -------
        Series or DataFrame
        """
        nv.validate_groupby_func("cumsum", args, kwargs, ["numeric_only", "skipna"])
        if axis != 0:
            f = lambda x: x.cumsum(axis=axis, **kwargs)
            return self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj, is_transform=True)

        return self._cython_transform("cumsum", **kwargs)
```

I don't have any experience with Cython, and maybe that isn't the reason behind it, so can anyone point out to me why lists/strings aren't viable here?

Comment: I think most things are not made to work with lists in pandas/numpy. Keep in mind that repeatedly adding a list/string is O(n**2) ;)

Comment: @mozway Re your 2. point: I'm well aware and usually don't do that :))

Comment: And `df.groupby("group").apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())` is a workaround (I know you don't want one, but might be useful to other readers)